# Convert VARCHAR 24 Hour Time to 12 Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, format

I have a 24 hour time, `start_time`, that is stored as `varchar` (no control over this). I need to convert it to 12 hour with AM/PM.

Examples:

- `17:45` should become `5:45 PM`
- `09:00` should become `9:00 AM`

Comment: Why are you storing a time as a `varchar` at all? the `time` data type exists for a reason? You say you have no control, but *someone* does.

Comment: It's not _me_ storing it as that. Trust me, if I had a choice it wouldn't be. It's our PMS system (hotel) from a third-party company, they're not going to change it.

Comment: Also why 12 hour? if you *are* using a `varchar`, `hh:mm` is vastly better than `h:mm AM/PM`. Unless you *want* `'12:00 AM'` to be **after** `'11:59 PM'`?

Comment: It's the required format for import into another third-party program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy with `FORMAT` function:

```sql
SELECT timestr
     , FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, timestr, 108), 'h:mm t')
     , FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, timestr, 108), 'h:mm tt')
FROM (VALUES
    ('17:45'),
    ('09:00')
) t(timestr)
```

Note that `tt` format specifier does not work with time datatype.

Comment: I'm always very careful with `FORMAT`. Although it is a "great" function for getting formats very easily, it's always a great performance killer.

Answer (score 2):

Do multi conversations :

```
select convert(varchar(20), convert(time(0), start_time), 100)
from table t;
```

**EDIT :**

Use `apply` :

```
select stuff(time_c, len(time_c)-1, 0, ' ')
from table t cross apply
     ( values (convert(varchar(20), convert(time(0), start_time), 100)) 
     ) t(time_c)
```

Comment: How do I add a space between the time and AM/PM to this? Currently it gives `5:45PM` instead of `5:45 PM`.

Answer (score 2):

With a space between the time and AM/PM:

```
select replace(replace(convert(varchar(8), convert(time(0), '09:00'), 100),'A',' A'),'P',' P')
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should be fixing your design and I **strongly** suggest you do. The `time` data type exists for a reason, and the format of the value should be determined in the presentation layer, not in the RDBMS. If, you *have* to conver into the RDBMS in an inferior format, then you would need to `CONVERT` to `time`, and then back to `varchar` and use some string manipulation:

```
SELECT V.YourTime,
       STUFF(NewTime, LEN(NewTime)-4,3,' ') AS NewTime
FROM (VALUES('09:00'),('17:45'))V(YourTime)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(time(0),V.YourTime),109)))C(NewTime);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a64a598715e46ab5cad279aa1b47e3b6)

Comment: As discussed in comments on OP, it's not _my_ design. I have no say in what data types are used, unfortunately. I agree with what you're saying 100% and I wish I did have that option to fix it.

Comment: This is why I've still moved on to provide an answer, @WolfieeifloW, but not using the correct data types is so important. Altbhough you cannot, for reasons, that doesn't mean that future readers should not be reminded of the importance of good data choices; and that includes whomever designed your system and thought `varchar` was the right choice for a time. :)